# Cloud-based testing automation tools

Tags: selenium, testing, automated-tests, regression-testing

I try to find a service which provides a functionality that allow me to create manual tests autmation for web-based applications in simple way with visual constructor without any coding, so it could be

- simple in use without any coding on selenium or another framework tool
- has option to set testing in schedule mode via the web interface to perform regression testing
- has ID's validation and shows possible inconsistencies

The main point is reproduce manual tester's work without using automation scripts and do it in simple way in order to a beginner will be able to work with it.
So could anyone describe his own experience ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two main options I would consider

> to find a service which provides a functionality that allow me to create manual tests autmation for web-based applications in simple way

First one is [BrowserStack](https://www.browserstack.com) and you can record your Selenium tests using the Selenium IDE extension for FireFox. It can export the recorded steps into your favorite language (C#, Python, ect).  You can execute these recorded scripts on BrowserStack by pointing the hub URL to Browserstack's Selenium hub ‘http://hub.browserstack.com/wd/hub’ along with your username and Automate key. Your 'username' and 'automate key' can be found at Account --> Automate1, after you have logged in to your account.

I would suggest, you refer to the comprehensive [documentation](https://www.browserstack.com/list-of-browsers-and-platforms?product=automate) on BrowserStack Automate. It takes you step-by-step through the product and all its features. You can select the language you are using and get started with BrowserStack Automate. If you have any more questions, feel free to email at support@browserstack.com. They will be happy to help you out.

Second option is [SauceLabs](https://saucelabs.com/) and the Selenium [Builder](https://saucelabs.com/builder). This is the [docs](https://saucelabs.com/docs/builder) that will guide you. Further more you have [CI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration) integrations for [Jenkins](https://saucelabs.com/resources/articles/selenium-jenkins-how-to-do-it-yourself-and-the-sauce-labs-advantage) and [Bamboo](https://docs.saucelabs.com/ci-integrations/bamboo/).

Comment: That stuff directly use selenium or another language/framework, so is it possible to find something simplest ?

Comment: Well, the Selenium's capture-replay tools are both Firefox plugins (extremely easy to use). You don't need actually to write the code (since it's auto generated for you), just maintain the steps. Not that this is a good decision, because of the repetition and all, but if this is what you're after - IMHO..this is the simplest as it can be ..no better way to just record the UI tests and then execute ém against different browsers and OS.

Comment: Thanks, ekostadinov !

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Selenium IDE](http://www.seleniumhq.org/projects/ide/) to create your automated tests. With this Firefox plugin, you can record a test in your browser.

Once you're done recording, you can export the test and upload it to [TestingBot](https://testingbot.com). There you can specify the browsers you want to run the test on. TestingBot will then run your test across all the browsers you specified.